# how to insert nodes in red black tree node?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree

I had found this implementation in [github][1], i made some changes like adding a 2nd value to the node, and using each left and right node as a pointer Node the problem with the tree it is and whenever inserting nodes then searching in the nodes in the tree it only iterates through the tree from first to last pointers when using TMapFind which calls the function pointer TMapNodeComparison_F to compare pointers. I wonder what could be causing this bug I suspect it's something in the logic of TMapInsertNode checking if a node is black/red?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>



#define ASSERT_NOT_NULL(x) if(x)
#define ASSERT_NULL(x) if(x ==NULL)
#define ASSERT_NULL_(x,y) if(x== NULL && y==NULL)


typedef struct CByte
{
    unsigned char* value;
    size_t index;
    size_t length;
}BYTES;

//struct Data;
struct Node;
struct TMap;





struct Node
{
    CByte* value;
    size_t index;
    struct  Node* Left;
    struct  Node* Right;
    struct  Node* Parent;
    bool color;
};


typedef int  (*TMapNodeComparison_F) (struct TMap* map, struct Node* a, struct Node* b);
typedef void (*TMapNode_F)     (struct TMap* map, struct Node* node);

struct TMap
{
   struct Node* root;
   size_t TSize;
   TMapNodeComparison_F compareNodeFunction;

};


struct Node* TMapNodeAlloc() 
{
    return (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
}

struct Node* TMapNodeCalloc()
{
  return (Node*)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
}

struct Node* TMapInitializationNodeTree(struct Node* node,struct CByte* _data)
{
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (node) 
    {
        node->value = _data;
        std::string s  = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(_data->value);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        node->color = 1;//Initialize as Black
        node->Left = node->Right = NULL;
        node->index = _data->index;
       
    }
    return node;
}

struct Node* TMapInitializationCreateNode(CByte* _data)
{
    return TMapInitializationNodeTree(TMapNodeAlloc(), _data);
}

void TMapNodeDeAlloc(struct Node* node)
{
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL(node)
        free(node);
}

int AreNodesRed(struct Node* nodeA, struct Node* nodeB)
{
    return (nodeA && nodeB) ? !nodeA->color && !nodeB->color : 0;
}


static bool TMapIsNodeBlack (struct Node* node)
{
    return node ? node->color == 1 : false;
}
static bool TMapIsNodeRed(struct Node* node)
{
    return node ? !node->color : false;
}
static bool TMapAreNodesBlack(struct Node* nodeA,struct Node* nodeB)
{
    return nodeA && nodeB ? nodeA->color == 1  && nodeB->color ==1 : false;
}


static struct Node* TMapNodeRotateL(struct TMap* map,struct Node* node , int side)
{
    struct Node* blackNode = NULL;

    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (node) 
    {
        blackNode = !side == 0 ? node->Left : node->Right;
       /* blackNode->Left = blackNode->Right = (Node*)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));*/
        !side == 0 ? node->Left : node->Right = side == 0 ? blackNode->Left : blackNode->Right;


        node->color = 0;     //Red
        blackNode->color = 1;//Black


        side == 0 ? blackNode->Left : blackNode->Right = node;
        node->Parent = blackNode;
    }

    return blackNode;
}


static struct Node* TMapNodeRotateR(TMap* map,struct Node* node,int side) 
{
    struct Node* rightNode = NULL;

    ASSERT_NULL(node) 
    {
       

       !side ==0 ?  node->Left :node->Right = TMapNodeRotateL(map,!side == 0 ? node->Left : node->Right,!side);
        rightNode = TMapNodeRotateL(map,node,side);
    }

    return rightNode;
}

int TMapNodeComparison(struct TMap* map, struct Node* a, struct Node* b)
{
    return (a->value > b->value) - (a->value < b->value);
}


void TMapNodeDealloc(struct TMap* map, struct Node* node) 
{

    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (map) 
    {
        ASSERT_NOT_NULL (node) 
        {
            TMapNodeDeAlloc(node);
        }
    }
}


struct TMap* TMapAlloc()
{
    return (TMap*)malloc(sizeof(TMap));
}

struct TMap* TMapInitialize(struct TMap* map, TMapNodeComparison_F node_cmp_cb) 
{
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (map)
    {
        map->root = NULL;
        map->TSize = 0;
        map->compareNodeFunction = node_cmp_cb ? node_cmp_cb : TMapNodeComparison;
    }
    return map;
}


struct TMap* TMapCreate(TMapNodeComparison_F node_cb) 
{
    return TMapInitialize(TMapAlloc(), node_cb);
}

void TMapDealloc(struct TMap* map, TMapNode_F node_cb)
{
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL(map) 
    {
        ASSERT_NOT_NULL(node_cb)
        {
            struct Node* node = map->root;
            struct Node* save = NULL;

         
            while (node) 
            {
                ASSERT_NULL (node->Left) 
                {

                   
                    save = node->Right;
                    node_cb(map, node);
                    node = NULL;
                }
                else 
                {

                   
                    save = node->Left;
                    node->Left = save->Right;
                    save->Right = node;
                }
                node = save;
            }
        }

        free(map);
    }
}


int
rb_tree_test(struct TMap* map, struct Node* root) 
{
    int lh, rh;

    if (root == NULL)
        return 1;
    else 
    {
        struct Node* ln = root->Left;
        struct Node* rn = root->Right;

        /* Consecutive red links */
        if (TMapIsNodeRed(root))
        {
            if (AreNodesRed(ln,rn)) 
            {
                printf("Red violation");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        lh = rb_tree_test(map, ln);
        rh = rb_tree_test(map, rn);

        /* Invalid binary search tree */
        if
          ((ln != NULL && map->compareNodeFunction(map, ln, root) >= 0)
        || (rn != NULL && map->compareNodeFunction(map, rn, root) <= 0))
        {
            puts("Binary tree violation");
            return 0;
        }

        /* Black height mismatch */
        if (lh != 0 && rh != 0 && lh != rh) 
        {
            puts("Black violation");
            return 0;
        }

        /* Only count black links */
        if (lh != 0 && rh != 0)
            return TMapIsNodeRed(root) ? lh : lh + 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

void* TMapFind(struct TMap* map, CByte* value) 
{
    void* result = NULL;

    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (map) 
    {
        struct Node node;
        node.value = value;


        struct Node* it = map->root;
        int cmp = 0;
        while (it) 
        {
            if ((cmp = map->compareNodeFunction(map, it, &node))) 
            {

                it = cmp < 0   ? it->Right : it->Left;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        result = it ? it->value : NULL;


    }
    return result;
}

#define CompareANullElement(nonNull,Null) ((!Null || !nonNull)  ? (0) : nonNull==Null)


int TMapInsertNode(struct TMap* self, struct Node* node) 
{
    int result = 0;
    if (self && node) 
    {
        ASSERT_NULL (self->root) 
        {
            self->root = node;
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            struct Node head = { NULL };
            struct Node* g, * t;       
            struct Node* p, * q;       
            int dir = 0, last = 0;

            // Set up our helpers
            t = &head;
            g = p = NULL;
            q = t->Right = self->root;

           

            while (1) 
            {
                ASSERT_NULL (q) 
                {

                    // Insert node at the first null link.
                    p->Left = q = node;
                }
                else if (AreNodesRed(q->Left,q->Right))
                {
                   
                
                    q->color = 0;//red
                    q->Left->color = 1;// black 
                    q->Right->color = 1;// black 
                }

                if (AreNodesRed(q,p)) 
                {



                    int dir2 = CompareANullElement(t->Right,g);
                    
                    if (CompareANullElement(q,(last  == 0 ? p->Left : p->Right)))
                    {
                        t->Right = TMapNodeRotateL(self,g,!last);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        t->Left = TMapNodeRotateR(self,g,!last);
                    }
                }

                // Stop working if we inserted a node. This
                // check also disallows duplicates in the tree
                if (self->compareNodeFunction(self, q, node) == 0) 
                {
                    break;
                }

                last = dir;
                dir = self->compareNodeFunction(self, q, node) < 0;

                // Move the helpers down
                if (g != NULL) 
                {
                    t = g;
                }

                g = p, p = q;

                q = dir ==0 ? q->Left : q->Right;
            }

            // Update the root (it may be different)
            self->root = head.Right;
        }

        // Make the root black for simplified logic
        self->root->color = 1;
        ++self->TSize;
    }

    return 1;
}

int TMapInsert(struct TMap* map, CByte* value) 
{
    return TMapInsertNode(map, TMapInitializationCreateNode(value));
}

int TMapRemoveFrom(struct TMap* map, CByte* value, TMapNode_F node_cb)
{
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (map->root)
    {
        struct Node head = { 0 }; 
        struct Node node;
        node.value = value ; 
        struct Node* q, * p, * g;
        struct Node* f = NULL;  
        int dir = 1;

        q = &head;
        g = p = NULL;
        q->Right = map->root;

        
        while ((dir == 0 ? q->Left : q->Right) != NULL) 
        {
            int last = dir;

        
            g = p, p = q;
            q = dir == 0 ? q->Left : q->Right;
            dir = map->compareNodeFunction(map, q, &node) < 0;

           
            if (map->compareNodeFunction(map, q, &node) == 0) 
            {
                f = q;
            }

            // Push the red node down with rotations and color flips
            if (TMapIsNodeBlack(q) && TMapIsNodeBlack(dir == 0 ? q->Left : q->Right)) 
            {
                if (TMapIsNodeRed(!dir == 0 ? q->Left : q->Right))
                {
                    p = last == 0 ? p->Left : p->Right = TMapNodeRotateL(map,q,dir);
                }
                else if (TMapIsNodeBlack(!dir == 0 ? q->Left : q->Right))
                {
                    struct Node* s = !last == 0 ? p->Left : p->Right;
                    if (s) 
                    {
                        if (TMapAreNodesBlack(!last == 0 ? s->Left : s->Right,last == 0 ? s->Left : s->Right)) 
                        {

                            // Color flip
                            p->color = 1;
                            s->color = 0;
                            q->color = 0;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            int dir2 = g->Right == p;
                            if (TMapIsNodeRed(last == 0 ? s->Left : s->Right)) //check for red
                            {
                                dir2 == 0 ? s->Left : s->Right  = TMapNodeRotateR(map,p,last);
                            }
                            else if (TMapIsNodeBlack((last != 0 ? s->Left : s->Right)))
                            {
                                dir2 == 0 ? g->Left: g->Right = TMapNodeRotateL(map,p,last);
                            }

                            // Ensure correct coloring
                            q->color = dir2 == 0 ? g->Left->color  : g->Right->color = 0;
                            dir2==0 ?   g->Left->Left->color : g->Right->Left->color = 1;
                            dir2 == 0 ? g->Left->Right->color :  g->Right->Right->color = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Replace and remove the saved node
        ASSERT_NOT_NULL (f) 
        {
            CByte* tmp = f->value;
            f->value = q->value;
            q->value = tmp;

            p->Right == q ?  p->Right : p->Left =  ((q->Left == NULL) ?  q->Right: q->Left);

            ASSERT_NOT_NULL (node_cb) 
            {
                node_cb(map, q);
            }
            q = NULL;
        }

        // Update the root (it may be different)
        map->root = head.Right;

        // Make the root black for simplified logic
        if (map->root != NULL) 
        {
            map->root->color = 1;
        }

        --map->TSize;
    }
    return 1;
}

int TMapRemoveTree(struct TMap* map, CByte* value)
{
    int result = 0;
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (map)
    {
        result = TMapRemoveFrom(map, value, TMapNodeDealloc);
    }
    return result;
}

size_t TMapGetSize(struct TMap* map) 
{
    size_t result = 0;

    ASSERT_NOT_NULL(map)
    {
        result = map->TSize;
    }

    return result;
}



int my_cmp_cb(struct TMap* self, struct Node* node_a, struct Node* node_b)
{
    BYTES* a = (BYTES*) node_a->value;
    BYTES* b = (BYTES*) node_b->value;
    return  (a->value > b->value) - (a->value < b->value);
}
int main()
{
    int t = true;
    int d,c = 1;
    (t ? d : c) = 2;

    struct TMap* tree =  TMapCreate(my_cmp_cb);
    std::cout << sizeof(*tree) << std::endl;


    ASSERT_NOT_NULL (tree) 
    {

        BYTES* bytes = (BYTES*)calloc(1000,sizeof(BYTES));
        std::stringstream ss;
        // Use the tree here...

        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
        {
            // Default insert, which allocates internal rb_nodes for you.
            ss << i;
            auto message = std::string("Hello " + ss.str());
            unsigned char* val = new unsigned char[message.length() + 1];

            strcpy((char*)val, message.c_str());

            bytes[i].value = val;
            bytes[i].index = i;
            bytes[i].length = sizeof(message) / sizeof(unsigned char*);
            TMapInsert(tree, &bytes[i]);
            ss.str("");
            ss.clear();
        }
        std::string str ="Hello 2";

         BYTES b { (unsigned char*)str.c_str(), 2, 8 };
        // To f

        BYTES* f = (BYTES*)TMapFind(tree, &b);
        
        
        
        
        
        
        if (f) 
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "found BYTES(value = %s, index = %ull, length = %ull )\n", f->value,f->index,f->length);
        }
        else {
            printf("not found\n");
        }

        TMapDealloc(tree, NULL);
    }
    
}


  [1]: https://github.com/mirek/rb_tree/blob/master/rb_tree.c
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c++? It looks like c, except for the headers, that you don't even appear to be using. You do have a `reinterpret_cast`, but that can be replaced by a c-style cast. If you *do* want to write c++, then there are *many* improvements to be made.

Comment: currently I am trying to compile it using MSVC so not exactly a C compiler

Comment: Ok, but doesn't MSVC compile c as well?

Comment: @cigien I think I saw a `std::string` being used somewhere, but yes this code looks like c++ without classes

Comment: @cigien MSVC compiles only pre-C99 C

Comment: @john Oh, I didn't know that.

Comment: later I plan to implement it on a project using C++ but need to run a separate kernel in C hence the code in C

Comment: @cigien Using C++ headers seems like a perfectly accurate reason to use the C++ tag.  It means they are using a C++ compiler and thus it is C++ code.  A program not making full use of C++ features does not become a C program.  Even code that perfectly follows both the C and C++ standards can act functionally different depending on whether it was built with a C compiler or C++ compiler, so one should tag the C++ language when using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Sure, that's fine. I was just clarifying why the OP had the tag.

Comment: if the posted code is C++, then why the calls to `calloc()`, `malloc()` and `free()`?  Shouldn't you use: `new` and `delete`

Comment: @user3629249 as I explained before I plan to use it on a written-in-C kernel